# OrientDB append field to perform join

Tags: join, append, nodes, orientdb, document

I'm manipulating a document collection and an edge collection, and I want to perform a join operation  to get details from the document collection.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

first: `select from l2 where p = "568700933"` 
the join attribute in the other collection has as a value `p = 568700933;`

Second `select Entry from P where reference = p+";"`

and third return the Entry and p .

I have no clue how to join this

When I try `select from a , b` I get an error

What I need is:

```
Select from  edge  node of key p = "568700933" , get the assosiated details from the document collection of the same key , knowing that the document collection had p = "568700933;"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no JOIN in OrientDB, you just cannot do it. Queries accept only a single target.

In a graph database, you define relationships as edges, not as pk/fk and join.
Once you have your edges, you can use SELECT with `out()/in()` functions or MATCH to traverse them (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Match.html)

[edit] here is a practical example on how to do this with OrientDB.

Suppose you have two vertex classes `ClassP` and `ClassQ` and and edge class called `ClassE`

First of all let's create the schema:

```
CREATE CLASS ClassP EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS ClassQ EXTENDS V;

CREATE CLASS ClassE EXTENDS E;
```

Now let's populate it with some data:

```
CREATE VERTEX ClassP SET name = 'foo';
CREATE VERTEX ClassP SET name = 'bar';

CREATE VERTEX ClassP SET id = 1;
CREATE VERTEX ClassP SET id = 2;
```

And connect them through edges:

```
/* from "foo" to "1" */

CREATE EDGE ClassE  
 FROM 
  (SELECT FROM ClassP WHERE name = 'foo')
 TO
  (SELECT FROM ClassQ WHERE id = 1)
 SET myEdgeProp = 'x';


/* from "foo" to "2" */

CREATE EDGE ClassE  
 FROM 
  (SELECT FROM ClassP WHERE name = 'foo')
 TO
  (SELECT FROM ClassQ WHERE id = 2)
 SET myEdgeProp = 'y';


/* from "bar" to "2" */

CREATE EDGE ClassE  
 FROM 
  (SELECT FROM ClassP WHERE name = 'bar')
 TO
  (SELECT FROM ClassQ WHERE id = 2)
 SET myEdgeProp = 'z';
```

Now we can query the dataset as follows:

```
/* get the name of a vertex and all the connected IDs */

SELECT name, out("ClassE").id FROM ClassP WHERE name = 'foo';
```

or

```
MATCH
  {class:ClassP, as:a, where:(name = 'foo')} -ClassE-> {as:b}
RETURN a.name as name, b.id as id
```

or

```
/* return all the details for all the vertices */

MATCH
  {class:ClassP, as:a, where:(name = 'foo')} -ClassE-> {as:b}
RETURN $elements
```

I hope it helps

Comment: then what is the aport of Multimodel database ?  if we can not handle both documents and graphs at the same time ? so it is not possible to test how fast it is I just sum the time of document query and graph query seperately then sum it ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean... JOIN is not an operation for Document model... You don't need to do separate queries for document and graph, you can just write a simple MATCH query and return all you need

Comment: If not  a join then what is it , I might me mistaken using that term . I edited the quetion saying what I need to get hope you would help on it

Comment: Luigi your answer is used when we have created the edge fromlinking  the documents . for my cas the documents and the edges are imported separetely .